# how do we disable and remove script console (groovy) from jenkins

Tags: jenkins-groovy, script-console

i wanted to disable and remove the script console(groovy) from Jenkins, just need is there any option to remove that from Jenkins so that no one can use and run any command.

we wanted to remove this because of security purpose, please confirm me with the explanation.

Comment: It think it is not possible to disable the script console but you can implement `Matrix-based security` to provide necessary authorization (who can do what). **Manage Jenkins --> Configure Global Security --> Authorization --> Matrix-based security**

Comment: If unable to see the Matrix-based secruity, please install the plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth